# Parsing XML with structured element names

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I've got some third party XML to parse in the following form. The number of tests is unbounded, but always an integer.

```
<tests>
    <test_1>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_1>

    <test_2>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_2>

    <test_3>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_3>
</tests>
```

I'm currently parsing this with XPath, but it's a lot of messing around. Is there any way of expressing this style of XML in a XSD schema and generating JAXB classes from it.

As far as I can see this is impossible, the only thing possible is the `<xs:any processContents="lax"/>` technique from 
[how can I define an xsd file that allows unknown (wildcard) elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943659/how-can-i-define-an-xsd-file-that-allows-unknown-wildcard-elements)
, however this allows any content, not specifically `<test_<integer>`. I just want to confirm I'm not missing some XSD/JAXB trick?

Note I would have preferred the XML to be structured like this. I may try to convince the third-party to change.

```
<tests>
    <test id="1">
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test>

    <test id="2">
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test>

    <test id="3">
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: XSD's are centered around a fixed set of elements/types. JAXB simply creates classes from them. How could the number of different elements with the naming scheme "test_xxx" be determined? --- I see an alternative, however: First use an XSLT to change the incoming XML with those elements to one that fits your needs and uses the `<test id="xxx">` naming scheme. For that you can easily write an XSD and generate JAXB classes from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are ways of dealing with elements with structured names such as numeric suffixes,

- **XPath**: Use string tests against `name()` or `local-name()`
- **XSD**: See [XSD element name pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568670/xsd-element-name-pattern-matching)
- **JAXB**: See [Dealing with poorly designed XML with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616332/dealing-with-poorly-designed-xml-with-jaxb)

you ***really should fix the underlying XML design*** (`test_1` should be `test`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is full working example of using XSLT to transform the `<test_N>` input into `<test id="N">` style

```
<tests>
    <test_1>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_1>
    <test_2>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_2>
    <test_1234>
        <foo bar="baz" />
    </test_1234>
    <other>
        <foo></foo>
    </other>
</tests>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), 1, 5) = 'test_']">
        <xsl:element name="test">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="substring(name(), 6, string-length(name()) - 5)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code

```
File input = new File("test.xml");
File stylesheet = new File("test.xsl");

StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(input), new StreamResult(writer));

System.out.println(writer);
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test id="1">
        <foo bar="baz"/>
    </test>

    <test id="2">
        <foo bar="baz"/>
    </test>

    <test id="1234">
        <foo bar="baz"/>
    </test>

    <other>
        <foo/>
    </other>
</tests>
```